# Reuse app registration in ASP.NET Core web app for graph toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graph

I have an existing ASP.NET Core web app that is using Azure AD to authenticate and it is working fine. There is an existing Azure AD app registration.

Now I want to use MS Graph Toolkit to show a file list tree from Sharepoint.

I am using graph toolkit like this

```
<mgt-msal2-provider client-id="<clientid>"> 
<mgt-login></mgt-login>
```

If I use the client ID from another app registration it is working but I don't want the user to login twice. If I am logged in via azure ad and the app registration handling the Azure AD login has the right permissions can't graph toolkit reuse my credentials?